# How did ‘show’ become its own causative?

Tags: etymology

The [following Etymonline entry](https://www.etymonline.com/word/show) states: the original meaning of 'show' is ‘see’ or ‘look at’. Essentially a causative equivalent of ‘see’ (to show someone something, is to cause them to see it), the current signification arose around 1200, and only in English. Please speculate or hypothesize how this semantic shift occurred, even if it did **“for unknown reasons”**.

> **show** (v.)
>
> Old English *sceawian* ‘to look at, see, gaze, behold, observe; inspect, examine; look for, choose,’
>   from Proto-Germanic **skauwojan* (source also of Old Saxon *skauwon* ‘to look at,’ Old Frisian *skawia*, Dutch *schouwen*, Old High German *scouwon* ‘to look at’),
>   from Proto-Germanic root **skau-* ‘behold, look at,’
>   from PIE **skou-*, variant of root [**keu-*](https://www.etymonline.com/word/*keu-) ‘to see, observe, perceive.’
>
> Causal meaning ‘let be seen; put in sight, make known’ evolved c. 1200 **for unknown reasons [bold mine]** and is unique to English (German *schauen* still means ‘look at’). Spelling *shew*, popular 18c. and surviving into early 19c., represents obsolete pronunciation (rhymes with *view*). Horse racing sense is from 1903, perhaps from an earlier sense in card-playing.

Comment: @Mari-Lou It originated as a semantic causative within English. The current sense of _show_ is the causative equivalent to ‘see’ (in that it means ‘make sb. see’), and this is quite unusual considering that ‘see’ is itself the original meaning of _show_ (and still the only meaning found in its non-English cognates): verbs generally don’t evolve to mean their own causatives and lose their non-causative meanings. Originally, “He showed her the door” would have meant “He saw her the door”, which is meaningless. The question is asking how this unusual change in meaning occurred.

Comment: @Mari-Lou Done! (I’ve basically rephrased most of the question entirely, but I think it’s clearer now.)

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Thanks for the edit. I haven't reverted it, but have tried to shorten it? If you prefer your edit though, please revert mine to yours.

Comment: _OED_ offers some further explanation but there is no conclusion. Here is a relevant excerpt: " The details of the semantic development are not entirely clear; perhaps from ‘to look at’ to ‘to cause to be looked at or seen’ (compare branch II.), ‘to present, exhibit, display’ (compare branches II. and IV.), ‘to make known formally’, ‘to grant, award’ (compare branch III.), although all of the latter senses could alternatively show a development via sense 2 (‘to look for, seek out, to choose, select’). "